# Uncaught (in promise) Error - Apexcharts codes missing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm, apexcharts

I converted a HTML template into React. All parts of the template is displaying except for the apex charts. Supposedly the chart will be displayed at the main page.

[image: The location where the graph supposed to be]

[image: Error message from the console]

**What I've tried:**

1. Installing apex charts via npm

`npm install apexcharts --save`

`npm install --save react-apexcharts apexcharts`

2. Add apex chart js file at index.html

`<script src="assets/libs/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js"></script>`

This is my first time building a react project using a HTML template and apex chart. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated, thank you.

**EDITED**

I just realized that the codes for the apex chart is only visible when I inspect the code at a web browser (I'm using Edge and Chrome). But the codes are not in the source code when I check at my IDE. A total of 1961 lines of code are missing. I copy paste the code from the browser to my IDE to show how many line of codes are missing. But also after I copy paste the code, the graph appears without its interactive features. Supposedly, when I hover on the graph, a tooltip will appear but it don't.

[image: missing codes]

Why does some codes only appear in web browser? Do I need to import some packages or install something for the code to appear & work?